# Which is better for VS2010, VisualHG or hgscc (64 bit install)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial

Simple question, have you used them, which do you prefer?  Do either of them display the current branch in an easy to see place?

Edit: If you have a preference, please let me know why.  It is crucial in making an educated decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer VisualHG.

Comment: Ditto. I tried both a while ago and preferred VisualHg. It works via TortoiseHg rather than custom implementation and the code is on CodePlex. hgscc isn't bad at all, just not my preferred option